# Spring 3 MVC + Tiles 3 - nothing displayed

Tags: spring, tiles, tiles-3

I'm new to Tiles and trying to get Tiles3 working with Spring MVC 3.2.4.  I thought I had everything setup/configured correctly, but I am not getting anything displayed at all.  I've tried to enable DEBUG logging for org.apache.tiles, but nothing is showing up in the logs at all for tiles.

I am quite confused.  I presume that there must be something wrong with my paths or configuration, but I don't have the first idea where to start debugging Tiles to determine what it is looking for, or why something isn't being found.  I tried putting breakpoints on every public method in TilesView, but nothing is every called when I try to access a page.

webmvc-config.xml:

```
<!-- Tiles page resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
<property name="definitions">
    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

/WEB-INF/tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="secure/login" template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/default.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/secure/login/body.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

And I can confirm that the files /WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/default.jsp and /WEB-INF/views/tiles/secure/login/body.jsp exist.

I am hoping for an error message, or something at least, in the log output so I can start to figure this out, but I don't get anything at all.  The only thing I see that is tiles related in the output log is:

```
2013-10-25 13:55:05,034 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer - Found JSP 2.1 ExpressionFactory
2013-10-25 13:55:05,082 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
```

Where/how do I start?

I should add that I currently had the application working with Tiles2 successfully, and was trying to upgrade to Tiles3 but am having no luck.

The controller looks like:

SecureController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/secure/**")
@Controller
public class SecureController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "secure/login";
    }
}
```

And I can confirm that the "return secure/login" statement is being executed.

log4j.xml:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c{5} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Some other loggers here too -->

    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <logger name="org.apache.tiles">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>


    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

pom.xml snippet:

```
    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

URL being accessed:  //localhost:8080/myapp/secure/login

Comment: How are you making the request (i.e. what's the url path?) What does your controller look like? What does your log4j.xml look like? You really have not provided enough for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: @kungfuters I've updated the question with the additional info you requested.  I didn't put those in originally, as I thought they were fairly trivial, but have added them in.

Comment: Problem resolved.  Stupid error.  Had an InternalResourceViewResolver buried in the configuration much higher up that I hadn't seen.  Removed it an all works as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.  Leaving this post in case someone else runs into the problem.  I had missed a configuration higher up in the config file that set an InternalResourceViewResolver.  Unfortunately, Spring can only handle one UrlViewResolver or InternalResourceViewResolver in the chain.  Without specifying an order preference, Spring was trying to use the InternalResourceViewResolver (JstlView) and completely skipping over the Tiles view resolver.

Removed the other view resolver, and all works as expected.